# IBM MQ: How to handle open/close connections on long running services/workers

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm using .NET Core to write a Worker Service ([Worker Services in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers)) which will connect to a IBM MQ queue to read messages of it. This will be done continuously in a long running process (process will be running until service is stopped).

My questing is: What kind of *connection-strategy is the recommended* usage when running *long processes* with IBM MQ?

I see three alternatives:

1. **One connection throughout the application lifetime** Open the connection *once* at application start. Keep reading messages of the
   queue. Close the connection when the application stops. If the
   connection accidentally stops, use the appropriate autoconnect flags
   to reconnect to the queue automatically (if possible).
2. **Open a new connection for every read from the queue** Every time we need to read from the queue, open a new connection to the queue and queue-manager and read one message. Close both connections when reading is done.
3. **Open a new connection and process items in the queue until empty** Open a connection when we want to process messages. Process all messages in the queue until all messages are processed. When all messages are processed, close the connection.

Alternative two doesn't seem like an option. But what is the *recommended* connection procedure in this scenario for both queue *and* queue-manager?

Comment: Connect to queue manager and open queue once and process messages until application is asked to stop. While stopping application close the queue and connection. I would also suggest to use automatic client reconnection so that underlying MQ .NET library takes are of reconnecting to queue manager in case of connection broken errors.

Comment: Option 3 would be recommended for triggered applications. Triggered applications would be recommended if you have long gaps with no messages to process. This means that the application stops when there is no work, and then is automatically started up when messages arrive. Option 1 would be recommended for a non-triggered, always running, application.

Comment: A wise customers told me.
Have long running connection
If no messages have been received in random 45-90 mins then disconnect.
This has the advantages that connections are closed (perhaps overnight) which means you do not have thousands of connections doing nothing,  It also means your connections have to reverify at least once a day, and you do not have a session running with an expired password or certificate for very long.   If you are using an older version of MQ, and clients, you can have it connect to a different queue manager and so do load balancing ( under your control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not the "official" connection procedure for a long running connection, I settled on **option 1**: *One connection throughout the application lifetime* with the appropriate connection-flags for handling automatic reconnect.